# HTTPS works only under my WIFI

Tags: apache, ssl, web, https

I've a very weird problem with https.

I installed a new ssl certificate on my subdomain beta.gosherpy.com and when I try to access from any device here in my office using this wifi https://beta.gosherpy.com works perfectly. As soon as I use mobile 3G or another wifi the response is "cannot connect to the server".

I talked to GOdaddy Customer care and they bring me to sslshopper and sslchecker tool which states that everything is good and correct.

I've no idea why under my wifi works outside not. any idea ?

Best

Comment: Is the server external facing?

Comment: Yes. you can easily access to http://gosherpy.com - now i'm trying maybe to create another virtual ip address and assign the ssl certificate to it

Comment: From Chrome I get the errore "connection refused" when trying to access over https

Comment: Have you published a DNS entry..?  You know what, this is now venturing far from programming toward server configuration.